# VirtualBox Installatation Issues

Tags: 14.04

This question has some relation to my previous question, but just read and see its different.

Whenever I Try to install VirtualBox in the software center it downloads fine. But after that it says Ubuntu 14.04 has experienced a internal error. Then I tried to run software center. But it said, Ubuntu had problems looking for updates(or something) So I went in the terminal(not Ctr Alt T, I Use dash, im weird) to type sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get upgrade. I Tried running the software center again. It worked. But it still said ubuntu was having trouble processing updates. So I Deleted virtualbox Via. The software-center to see if it worked. But system updates still wern't detected. I Was about to restart to see if it could do anything, But then it would update fine just when I Was about to click shutdown. However I Still want VirtualBox on Ubuntu, Or should I continue to run VirtualBox on my Windows 8 PC. Its just that I Think Debian/Ubuntu/Linux has a cleaner GUI to use.

PS : Still try not to get too advanced.

PSS : I May just stick to Windows VirtualBox.

-Cookie

Comment: Please try `sudo apt-get install virtualbox` and post the output if it does not work. Terminal will always be better than a GUI to troubleshoot that kind of problem.

Comment: It says no version to match the kernel. Other than that no errors. But when I got that i stopped the download. Because I Did not want the same thing to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the problem is of broken packages
Try fixing it using

```
apt-get apt-get -f install
```

or apt-get autoclean

```
apt-get clean
```

this function removes all the packages from cache
or try recovering it

```
dpkg-reconfigure <package_name>
```

i hope this should help and if does not try purging virtual box

```
apt-get purge
```

i hope these all codes should help if not then post some out put of function `apt-get -f install`

Comment: well... It seems pretty tedious. Mbby not

Comment: @cookiehuffman i cant get what do you mean my pretty tedious have you tried these codes

Comment: Umm, No, By tedious i meen a scary process for beginners, it kind of seems like messing with the system

Comment: none of these codes will mess with the system they will remove the mess created they are for situations that are weird if you want you can read the work of these codes on the ubuntu manual these codes only help increase the effecniency of ysytem by cleaning it

Comment: Err... I Don't have a manual :/

Comment: IT IS ON THE INTERNET https://help.ubuntu.com/